# customize gallery so that it belongs to one user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am using CarrierWave and as of now the gallery is open to the public with no ownership. I want to setup so that for one, the user does not have to create a Gallery. The only option should be to upload photos to their account and I want to limit each user photo uploads to 5 maximum. So if User 16 signs in, they have option to upload up to 5 photos to their profile. Once that limit is reach, if the user tries to upload more it should say "Maximum photos uploaded, delete to upload more". I'm not sure exactly how to pull this off.

photo.rb model:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :body, :gallery_id, :name, :image, :remote_image_url
  has_many :user, :through => :gallery
  has_many :gallery
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

    LIMIT = 5

    validate do |record|
      record.validate_photo_quota
    end

    def validate_photo_quota
      return unless self.user
      if self.gallery.user(:reload).count >= LIMIT
        errors.add(:base, :exceeded_quota)
      end
    end
end
```

photo controller:

class PhotosController < ApplicationController

```
  def new
    @photo = Photo.new(:gallery_id => params[:gallery_id])
  end

  def create
    @photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])
    if @photo.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created photos."
      redirect_to @photo.gallery
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
end

  def edit
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    if @photo.update_attributes(paramas[:photo])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated photo."
      redirect_to @photo.gallery
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    @photo.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed photo."
    redirect_to @photo.gallery
  end
end
```

galleries controller:

```
class GalleriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @galleries = Gallery.all
  end

  def show
    @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @gallery = Gallery.new
  end

  def create
    @gallery = Gallery.new(params[:gallery])
    if @gallery.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created gallery."
      redirect_to @gallery
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
    if @gallery.update_attributes(params[:gallery])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated gallery."
      redirect_to gallery_url
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
    @gallery.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroy gallery."
    redirect_to galleries_url
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Restricting user access**

To restrict user access to certain models I would use something like [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan).

It would let you do stuff like this:

```
## ability.rb
# Allow user to CRUD pictures belonging to own gallery
can :manage, Picture, gallery: {user: user}
```

In the controller you can then do stuff like this:

```
# picture_controller.rb
# assuming a nested route, e.g. galleries/1/pictures
load_and_authorize_resource :gallery
load_and_authorize_resource :picture, through: :gallery
```

This will make sure that each user only sees his or her own pictures.

**Restricting number of pictures in gallery**

I think your approach with the validation is okay.

I would simplify it thus:

```
validate :quota

private

def quota
  return unless user
  if gallery.pictures.count > 4
    errors[:base] << "Maximum photos uploaded, delete to upload more"
  end 
end
```

The error message should probably go into a locale file.

**Creating Gallery automatically for each user**

To do this, make sure that the Gallery model has a `belong_to` association to User. Then  create the gallery in a callback in the User model:

```
# models/user.rb
after_create :setup_gallery

private
def setup_gallery
  Gallery.create(user: self)
end
```

**General notes**

When you define your `has_many` relations, you should use plural names, like `has_many :users` or `has_many :galleries`.

Comment: Thank you very much for showing examples and explaining very well so I can learn! This works perfect. Though on a side note, I have created my own authorization/authentication. Not using cancan.

Comment: Also what is the difference is using singular vs. plural for the has_many since I been using singular without occurring any issues?

Comment: It may still work (in some cases), but the code will be non-standard and make less sense to you or other developers in the long run, and may break certain functions in Rails. An example: in your code, `@photo.gallery` will return a list of galleries. `@photo.galleries` would make much more sense, don't you think?